# Change CSS if number is greater than "x"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if this is possible, or I might be going about it the wrong way. I am iFraming a live data stream from my employer and need to be able to change the color of a specific div if the number contained in it is greater than say 5:00.

**So the code for the data stream looks like this**

```
<tr class="rowColour" style="background: #FFCFCF">
  <td style="text-align: left;width: 25%">Firstname.Lastname</td>
  <td style="width: 40%;">On Call (4:17 mins)</td>  
  <td style="width: 35%">Company 1</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rowColour" style="background: #FFCFCF">
  <td style="text-align: left;width: 25%">Firstname.Lastname</td>
  <td style="width: 40%;">On Call (0:49 mins)</td>  
  <td style="width: 35%">Company 1</td>
</tr>
```

So basically I need to look at what is contained in the parentheses (e.g. On call(0:49 mins)). So if that turns into 5:00 mins or greater, I need the color to be red.

But I really have no idea how to make this happen. Using jQuery contains selector I was able to do it for everyone that said "On Call" but I need it to only look at ones that are greater than 5:00 mins.

**Here is the jQuery I currently have:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".rowColour:contains(On Call)").css("color","red");
});
```

Is this doable? If so, how would I go about doing it? Any help would be VERY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the numbers, and as `5:00` can be converted to the number `500` you can check if it's above or below that etc. inside a filter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rowColour").filter(function() {
        var td = $('td:contains(On Call)', this);
        if (td.length === 0) return false;

        var time = td.text().replace(/\D/g, '');

        return time >= 500;

    }).css("color","red");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9kdm0yp/)